# Function that returns the binary string given its index in lexicographic ordering

Tags: number-representation

Index the binary strings in lexicographic order, so that the empty string " " corresponds to 0, the string "0" corresponds to 1, the string "1" to 2, and so on.

I want a function that, given a natural number $n\geq0$, returns the binary string with lexicographic index $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this function

```
bs[n_] := StringDrop[IntegerString[n + 1, 2], 1];

Table[{n, bs[n]}, {n, 0, 10}] // Grid
```

> ```
> 0      ""
> 1     "0"
> 2     "1"
> 3    "00"
> 4    "01"
> 5    "10"
> 6    "11"
> 7   "000"
> 8   "001"
> 9   "010"
> 10  "011"
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with:

```
encode[x_Integer?NonNegative] := StringJoin @@ ToString /@ Rest@IntegerDigits[x + 1, 2]
```

Test it:

```
In[7]:= {encode[#], #} & /@ Range[0, 6] // InputForm

Out[7]//InputForm= {{"", 0}, {"0", 1}, {"1", 2}, {"00", 3}, {"01", 4}, {"10", 5}, {"11", 6}}
```